# Viewing previous gdb commands

Tags: gdb

In a Unix terminal you can use the up arrow key to go back through previous commands, and it remembers these commands even if you close your terminal and open it again later.  Is there a way to do this with gdb?  When I close gdb it seems to forget previously used commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save gdb [gdb command history](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_183.html)

(gdb) set history save on

Answer (score 1):

Google for "gdb save history" gives this [link](http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/GDB/gdb_19.html#SEC188), which says you need to `set history save on`.